# Swagger Error A deterministic version of a JSON Schema object

Tags: json, swagger

This is the Schema definition.

```
serviceArea: [{
    states: [{
        type: String
    }],
    districts: [{
        type: String
    }],
    cities: [{
        type: String
    }]
}]
```

This is the swagger definition.

```
serviceArea: 
    - states: 
        - type: String
      districts: 
        - type: String
      cities: 
        - type: String
```

I am getting the above mentioned error. Please help. Thanks in advance.
Here is the swagger editor in the browser.[image: Error]

Comment: This is not a valid Swagger spec. How is your serviceArea object supposed to look like in requests/responses?

Comment: I have mentioned it above.

Comment: I think datatypes are lowercase, e.g. string rather than String, check an example and reformat

Comment: Yeah, I did that. Same error.

Comment: Please don't post code as images. You can paste the code directly into your question and use the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: Sorry about that... My bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `serviceArea` is supposed to be an object with properties `states`, `districts` and `cities`, the definition should look like this:

```
serviceArea:
  type: object
  properties:
    states:
      type: string
    districts:
      type: string
    cities:
      type: string
```

**UPDATE** with regard to OP's comments:

> It's an array of arrays.

An array of arrays is described as:

```
serviceArea:
  type: array
  items:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
```

Another error is here:

```
type:
  - number
  - "null"
```

`type` must be a single type such as `type: number`, not an array of types. Also, the OpenAPI Specification 2.0 does not support the `null` type. Some tools use the extension property `x-nullable: true` to indicate nullable types, so you can try this:

```
type: number
x-nullable: true
```

`nullable` will be supported natively in the next version, OpenAPI 3.0.

Comment: No it's not an object. It's an array and the properties you are saying, they are also arrays. How would you format it then?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. How is this array supposed to be formatted when sent/received via "try it out"? Is it simply an array of arrays, as in (JSON) `[ ["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e"] ]`?

Comment: Yes, It's an array of arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made some modifications. It's working.